# OnActivityResult not called on device

Tags: android, xamarin, onactivityresult

I try to select contact from contacts list:

```
contactsButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                //Create a new intent for choosing a contact  
                var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, Android.Provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
                //Start the contact picker expecting a result  
                // with the resultCode '101'  
                StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 101);
            };
```

and method **OnActivityResult** called under xamarin debugger and not called on my real device (SGS4).
When user cancels operation in contacts list, method **OnActivityResults** called under debugger and on real device.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            phoneNumberText.Text = String.Format("request={0}, result={1}", requestCode, resultCode);
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            ...
         }
```

**update**:
I don't understand why, but next line solves the issue: `contactPickerIntent.SetType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);`

```
    contactsButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        //Create a new intent for choosing a contact  
        var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, Android.Provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
        contactPickerIntent.SetType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);//(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
        //Start the contact picker expecting a result  
        // with the resultCode '101'  
        StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 101);
    };
```

Comment: add this line into OnActivityResult() function super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: no any errors/messages shown

Comment: but OnActivityResult don't called. If I add "super.onActivityResul()" how it can help?

Comment: compilation error "The name 'super' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line ***contactPickerIntent.SetType(...)*** somehow fixes the issue.

```
    contactsButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        //Create a new intent for choosing a contact  
        var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, Android.Provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
        contactPickerIntent.SetType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);//(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
        //Start the contact picker expecting a result  
        // with the resultCode '101'  
        StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 101);
    };
```

Answer (score -2):

I have never used xamarin but in terms of Android dev try changing the code onActivityResult code to:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        ....
}
```

Comment: do you mean, instead of type "Result" use type "int" ?

Comment: Ya that and override is usually done differently. But this could be an xamarin difference. I am just talking from an android stand point. Also check:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: what can be difference between debugger and real device for the user case?

Comment: Well, I think that virtual devices try emulate what a real device would do but sometimes it isnt completely correct and subtle differences will cause big problems. I always test on a wide variety of devices (never really use the emulators at all).

Comment: Right now I don't understand how to investigate the issue on my real device.

Comment: You could add some Log.d(..); calls throughout your program and monitor the life cycle.